# How to optimize this code to create document libraries

Tags: c#, algorithm, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

This is sharepoint code, but I know c# developers would understand it.

I cant think a way right now to optimize it.
The idea is to create a document library based on the creation of an event, The name of the document library is the startdate in some format + the event title.

The problem is when the user makes many events, the same day, with the same title.
I did it with an IF for only one occurence of the duplication.  But there should be another better way to do it.

The idea is to concatenate a number at the end of the doc library /1/2/3 etc.

```
using (SPSite oSPSite = new SPSite(SiteUrl))
            {
                using (SPWeb oSPWeb = oSPSite.RootWeb)
                {
                    if (oSPWeb.Lists[DocumentLibraryName] == null)
                    {
                        Guid ID = oSPWeb.Lists.Add(DocumentLibraryName, DocumentLibraryName + System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                        SPList oSPList = oSPWeb.Lists[ID];
                        DocumentLibraryLink = oSPList.DefaultViewUrl;
                        oSPList.OnQuickLaunch = false;
                        oSPList.Update();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        if (oSPWeb.Lists[DocumentLibraryName + "/1"] == null)
                        {
                            Guid ID = oSPWeb.Lists.Add(DocumentLibraryName + "/1", DocumentLibraryName + System.DateTime.Now.ToString(), SPListTemplateType.DocumentLibrary);
                            SPList oSPList = oSPWeb.Lists[ID];
                            DocumentLibraryName = DocumentLibraryName + "/1";
                            DocumentLibraryLink = oSPList.DefaultViewUrl;
                            oSPList.OnQuickLaunch = false;
                            oSPList.Update();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You say that 'The problem is when the user makes many events, the same day, with the same title' what its mean? document libraries created with same name?

Comment: yes! document libraries with the same name

Comment: that is necessary for save the document libraries with the same name?

Comment: thats what I need to avoid the duplication of document libraries names.

Comment: yes you change your code for creating document libraries. so the document libraries created with unique name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In pseudo-code:

```
string docLibNameBase ="myLibname";
string docLibNameTemp = docLibNameBase; //we start with the calculated title
int iCounter = 1;

//we check if the currently calculated title is OK
while (listExists(docLibNameTemp, yourWeb)) {
    docLibNameTemp = docLibNameBase + "/" + iCounter.toString();
}
//this is where you create the new list using docLibNameTemp as a good title


bool listExists(string docLibName, SPWeb web){
   try {
      //if there is no list with such name, it will throw an exception
      return (web.Lists[docLibname]!=null);
   } catch{
        return false;
   }
}
```